# Angular - Decorating Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use Angular's "decorator" capability to add functionality to some directives.  Assume that my directive's name is myDirective.  My code looks like this:

```
angular.module('app').config([
  '$provide', function($provide) {
    return $provide.decorator('myDirective', [
      '$delegate', '$log', function($delegate, $log) {
        // TODO - It worked!  Do something to modify the behavior

        $log.info("In decorator");
      }
    ]);
  }
```

]);

I keep getting this message:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myDirectiveProvider from app
```

To the best of my ability, the directives are already registered by the time the decorator function runs.  Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335574/decorating-the-ng-click-directive-in-angularjs

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This article shows how you can, in fact, use decorator() with directives.

You just have to include "Directive" as the suffix for the name. Hence, in my example I should have been doing

```
return $provide.decorator('myDirectiveDirective', ['$delegate', '$log', function($delegate, $log) {
    // TODO - It worked!  Do something to modify the behavior
    $log.info("In decorator");

    // Article uses index 0 but I found that index 0 was "window" and index 1 was the directive
    var directive = $delegate[1];
}
```

http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/

Comment: Fantastic, you learn something every day. Looking at the code, it seems `$delegate` should be a list of all of the directives in all loaded modules with the name `myDirective`. Seems potentially worrying that index 0 would be window, unless I'm missing something. 
You would have to watch out as the order in `$delegate` will depend on what order modules and directives are defined, so you'd need to keep this consistent. You may also want to remove unwanted directives from the list (`window`) - I'd still lean to sticking to documented ways unless you have to, but if you must this is very useful!

Comment: Adding the 'Directive' suffix is crucial!

Comment: This move doesn't work anymore, angular 1.4.x only allows the use of decorators in providers and services.

Comment: Juan, do u have a URL for this?

Comment: Maybe I am tired but I put Decorator instead of Directive! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

<s>Decorators as created with the `decorator` method are for **services** only. They have to be created with `service`, `factory`, `provider` or `value`.</s> See the docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#decorator).

If you want to decorate a directive, you can make another directive with the same name. Both directives will be used when the DOM is compiled, and you can define the compilation order using [priority](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Alternatively, if you are able to modify the code that uses the directive you are trying to decorate, then you can just make a new directive that uses the original in its template.

Comment: I found that you can use decorator for directives if you include "Directive" as the suffix for the name.  Hence, in my example I should have been doing $provide.decorator('myDirectiveDirective' ...

Comment: This is incorrect. See @blaster's self-answer, which shows how to decorate directives.