# Angular directive how to add an attribute to the element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm wondering what's the way to do work this snippet:

```
//html
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <a my-dir ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>

//js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{name:'John',id:1},{name:'anonymous'}];
    $scope.fxn = function() {
        alert('It works');
    };

})  
app.directive("myDir", function ($compile) {
    return {
        link:function(scope,el){
            el.attr('ng-click','fxn()');
            //$compile(el)(scope); with this the script go mad 
        }
     };
});
```

I know it's about the compile phase 
but I don't get the point so a short explanation would be 
very appreciate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decorating the ng-click directive in AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335574/decorating-the-ng-click-directive-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

#### A directive which adds another directive to the same element:

Similar answers:

- [How to get ng-class with $dirty working in a directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687011/how-to-get-ng-class-with-dirty-working-in-a-directive/21687744#21687744)
- [creating a new directive with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315312/creating-a-new-directive-with-angularjs/21317635#21317635)

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ziU8d826WF6SwQllHHQq?p=preview

```
app.directive("myDir", function($compile) {
  return {
    priority:1001, // compiles first
    terminal:true, // prevent lower priority directives to compile after it
    compile: function(el) {
      el.removeAttr('my-dir'); // necessary to avoid infinite compile loop
      el.attr('ng-click', 'fxn()');
      var fn = $compile(el);
      return function(scope){
        fn(scope);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

---

#### Much cleaner solution - not to use `ngClick` at all:

A plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jY10enUVm31BwvLkDIAO?p=preview

```
app.directive("myDir", function($parse) {
  return {
    compile: function(tElm,tAttrs){
      var exp = $parse('fxn()');
      return function (scope,elm){
        elm.bind('click',function(){
          exp(scope);
        });  
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work when using ng-repeat and calling a function on the directive's controller?  I've modified your plunker to show what I mean.  Note that the method being called on click is now on the directives controller.  Also note that the "This works" link which is not nested in an ng-repeat works while the others do not:  http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4ADmznnDCZvuxJrcZQ0?p=preview

Comment: Removing "my-dir" messes up my CSS specification. Is there a workaround to that? Thanks

Comment: you could have my-dir-unloaded attr and replace it to my-dir (or to my-dir-loaded) so CSS will work while directive wont get into an infinite loop (just guessing, didn't try)

Comment: @Dinesh `var fn = $compile(el, null, 1001);` and keep `my-dir` attribute intact.

Comment: It's not correct to simply call $compile() on the same element currently being compiled, it would recompile other, unrelated directives that happen to have greater priorities.

Comment: maybe this is a newbie question but how come you are passing "scope" as the argument for "exp"?

Comment: @IanDelairre $parse returns a interpolation function that must be called with a context. In this case, it would then call the function named `fxn` on the `scope`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

Comment: Directly using onClick skips the digest handling thats built into ngClick

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <a my-dir ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="fxn()">{{user.name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function AppCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.users = [{ name: 'John', id: 1 }, { name: 'anonymous' }];
        $scope.fxn = function () {
            alert('It works');
        };
    }

app.directive("myDir", function ($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {ngClick: '='}
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: Attribute is suppose to be added on the fly. Not from the template