# How to set ng-disabled inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My directive has

```
link: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs) {
    var status = $scope.item.status
    if (status) {
        var statusName = status.name,
            item = $scope.item;
        if (statusName === 'USED') {
            $attrs.$set('ng-disabled', true); // this doesn't work
        } else {
            $elm.attr('ng-disabled', false);
        }
    }
}
```

So, my question is:

How to apply ng-disabled to element with this directive?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would set `ng-disabled` to a scope variable, ex:

```
<input ng-disabled="isDisabled" />
```

And then inside your directive you can set that variable:

```
$scope.isDisabled = true;
```

Comment: Is this solution better then whisher's?

Comment: I think it's a matter of readability -- it's nice seeing the `ng-disabled` in the markup rather than adding it dynamically IMO, but both have the same result.

Comment: It's the angular way of doing things: avoid manipulating DOM.

Answer (score 15):

```
if (statusName === 'USED') {
    $attrs.$set('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {
    $elm.removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Why invoke ng-disable at all? You're already once evaluating the condition yourself, so having ng-disable evaluating it again is redundant.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't remember, why I used "ng-disabled" instead of "disabled" :)

Comment: According to the docs --

The HTML specification does not require browsers to preserve the values of boolean attributes such as disabled. (Their presence means true and their absence means false.) If we put an Angular interpolation expression into such an attribute then the binding information would be lost when the browser removes the attribute. The ngDisabled directive solves this problem for the disabled attribute. This complementary directive is not removed by the browser and so provides a permanent reliable place to store the binding information.

Comment: @Craig Appreciate the correction, but I still fail to see why it would be better to use ng-disabled in *this particular case*. Could you explain? I'm essentially *removing* and *adding* the disabled attribute, so it shouldn't matter whether browser discards it's value, should it?

Comment: You want to try to avoid manipulating the DOM when using Angular.

Comment: @Thierry J. Why that? Angular is absolutely fine for modifying the DOM. But do it with directives.

Comment: Yes, it is, but in this case you have a solution that completely avoids manipulating the DOM, which is IMHO more "angulary"

Comment: This is a better answer as it addresses the "inside of a directive" portion of the question. The accepted answer doesn't, that's an approach for a controller.

Answer (score 4):

```
//html
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="submit" mydir>
</div>
//js
'use strict';
            var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);
            app.directive('mydir', function ($compile) {
                return {
                    priority:1001, // compiles first
                    terminal:true, // prevent lower priority directives to compile after it
                    compile: function(el) {
                        el.removeAttr('mydir'); // necessary to avoid infinite compile loop
                        return function(scope){
                            var status = scope.item.status
                            if (status === 'USED') {
                                el.attr('ng-disabled',true);
                            } else {
                                el.attr('ng-disabled',false);
                            }
                            var fn = $compile(el);
                            fn(scope);
                        };
                    }


                };
            });
            app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.item = {};
                $scope.item.status = 'USED';
            });
```

credit to [Ilan Frumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687925/angular-directive-how-to-add-an-attribute-to-the-element)

Comment: will this also change the value of ng-disabled, if the item.status changes later?