# How do I set the tabindex (or any other attribute) of an AngularUI Boostrap tab heading link?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, tabindex, angular-ui-tabset

I'm using AngularUI Bootstrap like this to create a tabset:

```
...
    <tabset>
        <tab heading="First Tab">
           <div>First Content Here</div>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Second Tab">
           <div>Second Content Here</div>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
...
```

The code that is output to the page looks like this:

```
...
    <ul class="...">
        <li ng-class="..." heading="First Tab" class="...">
            <a href ng-click="select()" tab-heading-transclude class="ng-binding">
                First Tab
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="..." heading="Second Tab" class="...">
            <a href ng-click="select()" tab-heading-transclude class="ng-binding">
                Second Tab
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- tab contents here -->
    </div>
...
```

The problem I have, is the heading links can't be selected via the keyboard because they're missing a `tabindex`. Obviously, I can't just add that in because angular is creating the filler HTML for the list, and adding a `tabindex` to the tab element next to the heading attribute just adds it to the `li` and not the `a` tag where it needs to be.

**Is there a way to define a tabset and also pass in an attribute like a `tabindex` to be placed on the navigation (heading) links?**

Comment: Fairly sure the heading of the second tab is not going to be `"First Tab"`

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Typo, fixed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular directive how to add an attribute to the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687925/angular-directive-how-to-add-an-attribute-to-the-element)