# Add and compile attributes to angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive `<my-dir></my-dir>` and the directive should always have a specific functionality provided through angular attributes: `<my-dir ng-show="ctrl.shown"></my-dir>`. Here ctrl is the controller defined through `controllerAs: 'ctrl'` on the directive's definition.

I would like to simplify this directive and avoid mistakes by adding the attribute automatically when the directive is compiled. That way other users only have to type `<my-dir>`. Adding an attribute to a directive is simple, but these new attributes don't seem to get compiled.

```
app.directive("myDir", function() {
  console.log('myDir');
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'DirectiveController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    template: '<span>Controller Content</span>'

    // Attempt to attach the 'ng-show' attribute to the element

    link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
      $element.attr('ng-show', 'ctrl.shown');
    }

  };
});
```

I've tried a bunch of different things: adding the attribute in `link:`, in `compile:` and even using `$compile($element[0]['my-dir'])($scope)` after adding the attribute..

Example plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/PREavAIn1vqUdZYLsypt?p=preview

Example plnkr using the `ctrl.shown`: http://plnkr.co/edit/dTWIzClZG4YpE76AMCWk?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution by OP**

Based on [paul trone's answer to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35345248/5914556) I came up with a solution that works for me.

Basically I re-compile the element after adding angular attributes. To avoid infinite looping I also tag the element with a custom tag and stop compiling when an element is tagged.

This way I can deploy `<my-dir></my-dir>` multiple times, each with the implicit custom functionality at the root level of the directive. This way it is possible to use ng-show to hide the whole directive and not only the templated elements inside.

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').directive("myDir", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',                     // I prefer this directive to be Element-only
    controller: 'DirectiveController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    template: '<span>Controller Content</span>',

    /**
     * Add the necessary angular attributes
     *   along with a 'compiled' attribute as tag
     *   such that the element doesn't infinitely compile itself
     *
     * This still allows multiple of the same directive to be
     *   compiled at the same time
     */
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){

      // Check if the element has been tagged
      if(! tAttrs['compiled']) {

        // Tag the element so it doesn't compile again
        tElem.attr('compiled', true)

        // Add custom angular attributes
        tElem.attr('ng-show', 'ctrl.shown');

        // Recompile
        return function(scope) { $compile(tElem)(scope); };
      }
    }
  };
});

angular.module('app').controller("DirectiveController", function() {
    var shown = false;
});
```

Example : http://plnkr.co/edit/wbs0vcFmz15oL2twm6AC?p=preview

Alternatively it would have been possible to attach a watcher to a variable that toggles a class simliar to how ng-show works but that would start duplicating the exact functionality expected of the ng-show attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

so putting this logic into the **compile step** of the directive seems to be the right direction:

```
...
compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {

  // appears that you need to remove this attribute  
  // to stop the directive from looping infinitely 
  // through the compile step
  tElem.removeAttr('my-dir'); 
  tElem.attr('ng-hide', 'true');

  return function(scope) {
    $compile(tElem)(scope);
  }
}
```

Here's the updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/uyfJl8b1w5esYGv7SIsx?p=preview

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687925/angular-directive-how-to-add-an-attribute-to-the-element)

Comment: Are you sure? Last time I tried it it looped, triggering 1000x times before my browser gave up (Maximum call stack size exceeded), just like in your updated version :S

Comment: you're right, my plnkr is blowing up, trying other things.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I really didn't consider removing the directive.. EDIT : Aha - in your solution you move from an Element restricted directive to an Attribute directive. Now I understand why it worked/didn't work. :) Going to have to look further though

Comment: Update: Found an acceptable solution based on your suggestion, see my answer in this thread. :)

Comment: The line removing the 'my-dir' attribute is what I needed to get my code working (to prevent infinite recursion).  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand what you want to do correctly, but why don't you just add the attribute to the template like this?

```
template: '<span ng-show="ctrl.shown">Controller Content</span>'
```

Comment: Not really - adding `ng-show` to the template would still leave the directive `my-dir` visible and that's what I would have to avoid.