# Add a function to html string in link layer of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-sce

I got this directive which renders a list of objects. this objects got it's own function, i wanna bind it to a button. So i run over my items.In my objects value, i got a prop called Action which value is a function. i then try to add it to the html string, then i say it should be trusted as html. like shown below

```
angular.forEach(data.Items, function (value, key) {
      var buttonsCode = "";
      buttonsCode += '<div class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="' + value.Action + '">Test</div>';
      value["buttons"] = $sce.trustAsHtml(buttonsCode);
});
```

but when i try to run it, it looks like this

```
<div class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="function () {
    alert("test of funtion"); }">Test</div>
```

Anyone know how i can do this?

Comment: Check this post it will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687925/angular-directive-how-to-add-an-attribute-to-the-element

Comment: Thanks for the comment Amit,
I been looking at it, an from what i understand, he creates a directive that has a click event. my problem here is that i render a lots of buttons for a tabel. and can't see how i can hook the click event up with angular when rending the html for every row in the table.

Comment: After some more trying i found that i could be done with the answer given in the comment, so i will flag this as a dublicate