# Is it possible to configure ngTouch to add a slight delay on certain elements?

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, webkit, angularjs-ng-touch

I know ngTouch removes the default 300ms delay on mobile to make for a better mobile experience, but it makes mobile link taps occur so quickly that the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` style no longer works. There are a few elements that I need to have that highlight style. Is it possible to add attributes or get ngTouch to have at least a little bit of a delay for those elements, say 100ms? P.S. I tried adding the highlight style on the `ng-click-active` style and that didn't work. I also added a JS interceptor that applies a highlight class manually on click, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decorating the ng-click directive in AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335574/decorating-the-ng-click-directive-in-angularjs)