# how to extend angularjs 3rd directive like add ng-dblclick to element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using a `angular-tree-control` directive [angular-tree-control.js](https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control/blob/master/angular-tree-control.js) which does not support `ng-dblclick` function. I want to extend this directive and not modify it.

Comment: I'm using [link]{https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control/blob/master/angular-tree-control.js} which does not support ng-dblclick,any way to extend it but not modify it,I'm trying to google but not found clear solution...

Comment: Probably you are looking for `decorator`. I have checked and library you provided does not have double click event. Check this question, it could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335574/decorating-the-ng-click-directive-in-angularjs

Comment: The short answer is that directives cannot be extended.